# Plain JavaScript version of e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following jQuery based script you can stop the default action of dummy links, ie: `<a href="#">`

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

What would be the plain vanilla version of this script?

I'm not a JavaScript programmer but I'm thinking it may be something that uses `return false;`. Again, I may be totally wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You're right. Returning `false` from an event handler will prevent the default action.

Comment: @Barmar Only when using JQuery or inline-javascript.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) available in vanilla javascript as well. In a generic way you can always use `return false`. If you attach an event handler you are guaranteed to get event agument passed in the handler as opposed to using the `onclick` or any other attributes of the element (In which case you should rely on the specific event object available in side the handler which you may not get in all browsers, like in IE you would use `window.event`).

Ex: -

```
  document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener('click', function(e){ //say this is an anchor
         //do something
        e.preventDefault();
   });
```

So for all the anchors:

```
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for(i=0, len=anchors.length; i<len; i++){
     anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});
 }
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but is it necessary to add an ID to the `<a href="#">` in order for this version to work? Is there a more 'generic' way to locate the links instead? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo Nopes, you can just use `getElementsByTagName('a')` iterate through the collection and bind handler to it. It was a just an example for your question. :)

Comment: Got it. This one worked great and it's short. Thanks a lot for the explanations as well.

Answer (score 13):

```
// Like $('a'), gets all the <a> elements in the document.
var aElements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
// Create one function object instead of one per <a> element.
// The calling convention is the same for jQuery as for regular JS.
function preventDefaultListener(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
// For each a element,
for (var i = 0, n = aElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
  // register the listener to be fired on click.
  aElements[i].addEventListener('click', preventDefaultListener);
}
```

Comment: This worked great. The comments in the script rock. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Return false is the way to go. E.g. if your anchor already has an href:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="alert('clicked!');return false">Click me</a>
```

calling onclick like this will only perform the function, but not the navigation.

Comment: As I mentioned above, isn't it bad practice to put JavaScript on the markup itself? I've read somewhere several times. Just saying, I'm no JS expert.

Comment: I believe putting multiple statements might be not the best approach (the above is just proof of concept) but there's nothing wrong in attaching an event handler function this way.

Comment: Proof of concept, gotcha. However, I'm looking for a solution that's scalable and more 'generic' while staying on the best practices side. I'd like to use this solution for other projects.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use `return false;`

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;">test</a>
```

Comment: The `javascript:` there is not necessary.

Comment: @icktoofay, practiced using `javascript:`, updated answer. Thank you for the comment :)

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to put JavaScript on the markup itself? I've read somewhere several times. Just saying, I'm no JS expert.

Comment: @Ricardo: No, it's not, but some people have a "religious" objection to it.

Answer (score 0):

@Ricardo you are correct sir.

Not only does `return false` disable the default action for a said element, it prevents bubbling also.

```
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
```

is equal to

`return false;`

you decide :)

Comment: `return false;` does not prevent bubbling in native event handlers.

Comment: @user2736012, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ricardo: This answer states that `return false;` is equivalent to calling both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`. While that's true for jQuery's non-standard event handling system, it's not true for vanilla JS event handlers. When using `return false`, the event will still propagate (bubble) from the most deeply nested element that received the event, up through its ancestors, invoking any handlers it finds along the way.