# Hide # in URL when clicking <a href="#">

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```html
<p>
    <a href="#" id="sobo-einblenden">einblenden</a>
    <a href="#" id="sobo-ausblenden">ausblenden</a>
</p>
<div id="sozialbookmarks">
    <p>
        <b>Bereich für social bookmarks</b><br>
        Hier kommen nun die üblichen Verdächtigen und Logos dazu.<br>
        Nicht vergessen, meine Seite zu bookmarken!
    </p>
</div> 
<div id="sozialbookmarks2">
    <p>
        <b>Bereich für social bookmarks</b><br>
        Hier kommen nun die üblichen Verdächtigen und Logos dazu.<br>
        Nicht vergessen, meine Seite zu bookmarken!
    </p>
</div>
```

When I click on `<a href="#" id="sobo-einblenden">einblenden</a>`  in the browser I will see: `site.php#`. How can I make it so that the `#` is not added to the URL?

Comment: `return false` or call `preventDefault()` on the click event raised from those elements.

Comment: Why is usual to find this kind of links? If you don't need an anchor, why put `href="#"`? Write `<a href="javascript:void(0);">` it's better and you don't need extra functionality. It's valid also `<a href="javascript:;">`. Don't need an ficticional anchor that you need to avoid with extra javascript. Be serious.

Answer (score 1):

Use event.preventDefault()

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="return false;">link</a>

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Dhara Parmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37658490/6357231), you can use a simple jQuery event listener on all the `<a>` elements to prevent the default action (going to the hash) when clicked.

Here's a way to accomplish the same thing with vanilla JavaScript:

```
// all anchors
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // attach event to each anchor tag
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // prevent default action when clicked
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

There's a similar question regarding how to `preventDefault()` with vanilla JavaScript that can be [found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172084/plain-javascript-version-of-e-preventdefault)