# without checking full validation in js php file is opening

Tags: php, html

i need some help. i'm working on a form and it's something wrong. when i click on the submit button the without checking the full validation it is perform php action.
when i enter serial no in the form and click submit just to check the validation the page shows the text fields turns red but at the same moment it performs the php action. i don't know why.
here is the link
http://sujdhuj.com/dawood/

html form attributes

```
<form action="dbconnection.php"  method="post" name="2nd-form" id="form-survey" >

<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submitsurvey2" value="submit" onClick="validation()">
```

javascript code

```
function validation()
{
    flag=false;
    var Sno= document.getElementById('Sno').value++;
        if(Sno==null || Sno=="")
        {
            alert("Enter serial no");
            flag=true;
        }
    var Clientname= document.getElementById('Clientname').value

        if( Clientname==null || Clientname==""){
        document.getElementById('Clientname').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Clientname').style.borderColor="green";
        }

    var Contactno= document.getElementById('Contactno').value
        if( Contactno==null || Contactno==""){
        document.getElementById('Contactno').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Contactno').style.borderColor="green";
        }
    var Dos= document.getElementById('Dos').value;
        if( Dos==null || Dos==""){
        document.getElementById('Dos').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Dos').style.borderColor="green";
        }

    var Start= document.getElementById('Start').value;
        if( Start==null || Start==""){
        document.getElementById('Start').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Start').style.borderColor="green";
        }

    var End= document.getElementById('End').value;
        if( End==null || End==""){
        document.getElementById('End').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('End').style.borderColor="green";
        }


     var Dow= document.getElementById('Dow').value;
        if( Dow==null || Dow==""){
        document.getElementById('Dow').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Dow').style.borderColor="green";
        }


    var Osi= document.getElementById('Osi').value;
        if( Osi==null || Osi==""){
        document.getElementById('Osi').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Osi').style.borderColor="green";
        }



    var Emhr= document.getElementById('Emhr').value;
        if( Emhr==null || Emhr==""){
        document.getElementById('Emhr').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Emhr').style.borderColor="green";
        }


    var Er= document.getElementById('Er').value;
        if( Er==null || Er==""){
        document.getElementById('Er').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Er').style.borderColor="green";
        }


    var Mir= document.getElementById('Mir').value;
        if( Mir==null || Mir==""){
        document.getElementById('Mir').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Mir').style.borderColor="green";
        }


    var Ea= document.getElementById('Ea').value;
        if( Ea==null || Ea==""){
        document.getElementById('Ea').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Ea').style.borderColor="green";
        }


    var Cr= document.getElementById('Cr').value
        if( Cr==null || Cr==""){
        document.getElementById('Cr').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Cr').style.borderColor="green";
        }


    var Mir1= document.getElementById('Mir1').value;
        if( Mir1==null || Mir1==""){
        document.getElementById('Mir1').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Mir1').style.borderColor="green";
        }

    var Am= document.getElementById('Am').value;
        if( Am==null || Am==""){
        document.getElementById('Am').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Am').style.borderColor="green";
        }
    var Ca= document.getElementById('Ca').value;
        if( Ca==null || Ca==""){
        document.getElementById('Ca').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('Ca').style.borderColor="green";
        }
    var date= document.getElementById('date').value;
        if( date==null || date==""){
        document.getElementById('date').style.borderColor= "red";
        flag=true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('date').style.borderColor="green";
        }

    if(flag=true)
    {
      return  false;
    }
    else 
    {
      return true;
    }     

}
```

Comment: Try to change your HTML to `return validation()`.... And I would recommend working with `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: you may be interested in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172084/plain-javascript-version-of-e-preventdefault

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
if(flag=true)
```

condition is wrong.

It should be

```
if(flag==true)
```

change your type of submit button from 'submit' to 'button' then it will work
and try to post your form through Ajax

Comment: <input type="button" class="submit" id="submitsurvey2" value="submit" onClick="validation();">

Comment: @Vish744789 try <input type="button" class="submit" id="submitsurvey2" value="submit" onClick="return validation();">

Comment: thank you!!!! onClick=" return validation()" solved my issue.. really really thankyou

Answer (score 0):

well everything seems fine to me. However, a few pointers in my head:

1. Instead of calling javascript function on "onClick" event. Call validation function on "onSubmit" in form.
2. Define variable with "var" for the first time and then you can use variable without "var" keyword. e.g. var flag = false;

Try this and let me know if your JS validation works.

Comment: sir i tried what you suggest  me but sorry i didn't work

Comment: any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  var flag=false;
```

instead of     `flag=false;`

put `return  false;` after setting `flag = true;`